No internet connection with static IP only DHCP
I rent a room so I do not have direct access to the router. However, I have copied all of the information from the command prompt manually into the static IP box. The internet seems to work when I enable DHCP automatically, but not when I try to set a static IP address. 
And  that I used to input the static IP address. I'm on a virtual machine by the way, using Windows Server 2016. Any help is greatly appreciated.

"No internet connection" – Please clarify. Not even ping 8.8.8.8? Or just "websites don't show in my browser"? If the latter then probably it's because you did not set any address of DNS manually.

That's pretty common. You're trying to use a static IP in a range the DHCP server requires to be DHCP. Why are you wanting to use a static IP address?

Hey @music2myear can you explain a little bit more. I am using my homelab to practice some very basic helpdesk task. I am trying to practice setting a static IP address for this reason.  "in a range the DHCP server requires to be DHCP." can you please say more about this?

@Kamil Maciorowski Ping works fine, just no websites loading.

Networking is not my strong suit, this may be very wrong and is based on my own experience and interpretation of it: consumer network equipment is simple. DHCP on the router will route traffic for clients it has handed IP addresses out to. You entering things manually is not the same thing, even with the same IP, as the DHCP server handing out that IP. You would need access to the router/modem in order to configure it to have an address space it accepts but does not issue itself.

Ahh, that makes sense.. Entering things manually is not the same thing, even with the same IP. Thank you for this.

Try configuring the static settings with a  DNS server with gateway address 10.0.2. 2

@uggg please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

@music2myear: Usually it doesn't work that way. DHCP has nothing to do with routing individual addresses; that's all handled with ARP as a result of "being in the same subnet". A few networks are set up in a strict way where the router has regular ARP disabled and the DHCP server sets up "static" ARP entries from leases, and OP might be on one, but those are a rarity – certainly not consumer network equipment. (I don't think many enterprises do it, either? It's something you'd find in pfSense/OpnSense, rarely if ever elsewhere.)

you left DNS blank for a start. Question is ... WHY do you want a static NAT'd IP address?

@JaromandaX Hey, that is the problem I believe. Anyway I am doing a lab on Windows Server and following along with my own installation on my homelab. I do not see the DNS server listed when I type "ipconfig/all". Do you know the reason for this?

You've left DNS blank when you configured your IPv4 Address ... as clearly shown in your image

You left the DNS entries blank.
You'll  need those in order to translate servernames into ip-addresses.
Without DNS you can use  ip-addresses (like ping 8.8.8.8), but accessing things by name (like ping  www.google.com) won't work.
They are clearly visible in the ipconfig output: 75.75.75.75 and 75.75.76.76
These probably belong to the upstream ISP. You can use alternative DNS servers if you want as well.
E.g. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for Google DNS or 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 for Cloudflare.
There are many others. Just Google for "public DNS servers".
